# How to read Multiple Xlsx files having multiple work books in python dataframe using a loop

Tags: python, pandas, spyder

I have 15 xlsx files each having multiple worksheets. I want to dynamically loop it in such a way that all the worksheets and workbooks are read inside a single data frame.

I had tried using pd.read_excel in the following way

```py
filenames = glob.glob("*.xlsx")
dfList=[]
colnames =['dummy','dummy1','dummy2']
for a in filenames:
    df=pd.read_excel(a, sheet_name=None, header = None, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    dfList.append(df)

df= pd.concat(dfList, axis=0, ignore_index= True)
df.columns= colnames
```

The error I get when i run the pd.concat is

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

and also tried

```py
for a in filenames:
    df=[pd.read_excel(a, sheet_name=None, header = None, encoding = "ISO-8859-1").values()]
    dfList.append(df)
```

i get the following error

```
TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid
```

Comment: the code given there also does not work and the error is also mentioned in the query raised above

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need the concat?
Can you use `df = pd.DataFrame(dfList)` to convert your list to a dataframe

Comment: The list i think would have only list of multiple excel files but it is not able to read in the data in those excel files. Please correct me if i am wrong

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change:

```
filenames = glob.glob("*.xlsx")
dfList=[]
colnames =['dummy','dummy1','dummy2']
for a in filenames:
    df=pd.read_excel(a, sheet_name=None, header = None, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    dfList.append(df)

df = []
df = pd.concat(dfList, axis=0, ignore_index= True)
df.columns= colnames
```

Comment: it does not work i get the following error

Comment: the error i get is "TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type "<class 'collections.OrderedDict'>"; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame, and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid" and the code i used was "for a in filenames:
    df=pd.read_excel(a, sheet_name=None, header = None, encoding = "ISO-8859-1")
    dfList.append(df)
df=[]
df= pd.concat(dfList, axis=0, ignore_index= True)"